# How to get "Last Arrival Date" of a USB device using setupapi/cfmgr apis

Tags: windows, usb, setupapi

There is a property "Last Arrival Date" that is present for my USB device in the Device Manager UI.

[screenshot (device-manager/properties/details)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKPsw.png)

**How can I programmatically retrieve that value?** *I already have the corresponding handle (setupapi) and DEVINST (cfgmgr) which I use for everything else.*

***CLARIFICATION:***

It's somewhere nested under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_8888&PID_8888\SERIALNUMBER\Properties" but I can't see into that folder in the registry, either in regedit or in code. I get Access Denied. Of course I can fix that problem on my own development machine, but that's going to be a problem for customers who have standard, non-admin user accounts and have not added the permission necessary to read this data from the registry.

**I need a solution that works for any user.**

Comment: I think you should get familiar with SetupAPI and then try using `SetupDiGetDevicePropertyKeys` and `SetupDiGetDeviceProperty`, but I really am not sure about this.